# Mysql CURDATE() between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

How do i show the result when current date is between emphiredate (employyee hire date) plus one year
the query works well.

```
   SELECT 
        e.empFirst AS employees, e.holidays,
            @year := CEIL(DATEDIFF(h.date, e.empHireDate - interval 1 day)/365) AS Year,
               CONCAT(DATE_ADD(e.empHireDate, INTERVAL @year-1 YEAR),' to ',DATE_ADD(e.empHireDate  - interval 1 day, INTERVAL @year YEAR)) AS jon,
        COUNT(h.date) AS Days,
        SUM(h.hours) AS Hours,
       e.holidays - SUM(h.hours) AS Hours_Left
    FROM employees AS e
    LEFT JOIN holidaydays AS h ON e.empid = h.booking_id
    WHERE e.empid = booking_id and hours !=0
    GROUP BY Year, booking_id
```

RESULT:

```
employees  holidays Year    Date                   Days    Hours  Hours_Left
Jonathan    200      1   2014-10-10 to 2015-10-09   1       8          192
Arthur       0       1   2015-08-02 to 2016-08-01   1       10         -10
Mark        200      1   2014-10-10 to 2015-10-09   1       9          191
Jonathan    200      2   2015-10-10 to 2016-10-09   24      162         38
Jonathan    200      3   2016-10-10 to 2017-10-09    2      19         181
Mark        200      3   2016-10-10 to 2017-10-09    1       8         192
```

Because todays date is 2015-10-14  the result I would like is

```
employees  holidays Year    Date                   Days    Hours  Hours_Left
Arthur       0       1   2015-08-02 to 2016-08-01   1       10         -10
Jonathan    200      2   2015-10-10 to 2016-10-09   24      162         38
```

this is because todays date is between the dates can anyone help please.

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e24aa/2)

Comment: @CodeGodie any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
and curdate() > DATE_ADD(e.empHireDate, INTERVAL CEIL(DATEDIFF(h.date, e.empHireDate - interval 1 day)/365)-1 YEAR)
and curdate() < DATE_ADD(e.empHireDate  - interval 1 day, INTERVAL CEIL(DATEDIFF(h.date, e.empHireDate - interval 1 day)/365) YEAR)
```

Edited: Should now work with your dynamic dates - Also worth mentioning your SQL Fiddle schema has different hiredates than your examples.

Comment: Fixed - Will have to change the start dates in your Fiddle schema to reflect the same start dates you used in your expected results here.  Either way it works, though.